Uploading a geojson file to a geoserver with Python
I'm trying to figure out how to upload a geoJson via Python to my Geoserver. But it doesn't seem to be possible, neither a ".shp" file.
Is there any way to automatically upload such files? It seems that only .tif files can be uploaded.
However, if I can upload them manually, then I don't know if there is a way to do it automatically with Python.

The server config is responsible for which upload formats are valid; if it only accepts .tif, then that is what you need to send.

The thing is that I can manually upload tif files.

GeoServer provides a REST API to allow you to automate admin tasks like uploading files. See for example this question to see how to upload a shapefile, or you could read the manual.

This example not found and this is not a clear example
